# Hibernate INNER join doesn't work..SQL Query Works...Weird Behavior

Tags: hibernate

Query Returns zero records in HQL (Query 1 = Query 2 + Query 3):

Two OR conditions..Instead of returning results, it returns zero records

```
from Employee as emp where empState = 'ACTIVE' and exists (from EmployeeOrg as 
EmployeeOrg where 52 = 52 and ((EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable is null and 
EmployeeOrg.empId like '10002') or (EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable is not null and 
EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable.empId like '10002')));
```

Query2 Returns Records in HQL:

```
from Employee as emp where empState = 'ACTIVE' and exists (from EmployeeOrg 
as EmployeeOrg where 52 = 52 and ((EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable is null and 
EmployeeOrg.empId like '10002')));
```

Query3 Returns Zero Records in HQL

```
from Employee as emp where empState = 'ACTIVE' and exists (from EmployeeOrg 
as EmployeeOrg where 52 = 52 and (EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable is not null and 
EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable.empId like '10002'));
```

When we combine the condition - Query 1 results zero records

I suspect it is a hibernate bug or a default behaviour or query needs to be corrected.

Basically the OR and And condition doesn't work properly during joining multiple tables.

Thanks.

Comment: The Query 3 works fine when two exists are added instead of single with "OR" condition. example exist()...exist()..

Comment: Can you activate the logger `org.hibernate.SQL` to ALL and check the SQL generated by hibernate / copy it here?

Comment: The problem comes with joining tables....If it is empty hibernate behaves differently....i.e an explicity left outer join is required it seems..please comment.

Comment: Enable the logger so that we have the query. Also is EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable an oneToMany relationship?  if so is it isEmpty and no is null ?  Is it possible to do :  `select emp from Employee as emp left join EmployeeOrg.empDetailTable detail where empState = 'ACTIVE' and ((EmployeeOrg.empId like '10002' and detail is empty (is null?)) or (detail is not empty and detail.empId='10002')) `

Comment: I agree..My question is why we need an explicit join and why does hibernate doesn't take care of it.

Comment: Can you please give the generated SQL?   Need to check if it is a hibernate that generate a funny query or if there is a thing we miss on the jpql.

Comment: i forget to capture the generated query..let me check in the logs if i enabled the logging

Comment: It would be helpful to include the @Entity definitions.